# VisualStudio does not find namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Well, I'd like to use a class of a namespace in my Mainwindow.xaml

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbRcF.png)

As you see the namespace called `WPF.Tools`

Now I create a local at the top to the XAML

```
xmlns:webutil="WPF.Tools"
```

And in the Grid I have a WebBrowser where I'd like to use a a method of the class of the namespace:

```
<WebBrowser webutil:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource="{Binding SelectedRSSFeed.Link}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

If I hover over it it says: `The name "WebBrowserBehaviors" does not exist in the namespace "WPF.Tools".`

I also added a Project Reference so I don't think this is the Problem

Answer (score 0):

Your reference seems wrong.

It should be:

```
xmlns:webutil="clr-namespace:WPF.Tools;assembly=WPF.Tools
```